# Synchronize two directories on linux pc

Tags: sync, file-sharing, unison, sparkleshare, owncloud

I need a distributed filesystem (or a synchronization tool) that is capable of keeping a directory synchronized across 4 pc.

My requirements are:

- offline access (data must be available offline on each pc)
- preserve execution rights: some files are marked executable on a linux partition. This flag should be replicated.
- efficient sync strategy: some of my files are 20GB, they are changed quite often, but in very little parts (Virtualbox images). Delta transmissions are welcome.
- efficient handling of space: no history for files, files shouldn't be copied to temp directories "just in case you break it".
- it must propagate deletions of files
- modification can happen in any of the 4 pcs, they should be propagated when other pc are connected.
- solution must be fault tolerant: most of the time the 4 pc are disconnected/not able to synchronize.

Other specs of my solution are:

- Sync is over a lan, the total amount of data to be synced is around 180GB, in some ten thousand files. Changes are small, but can happen in large files.
- At the moment i'm interested in a linux only solution.
- Simple merge strategy: conflicts either don't happen or are solved with "last one wins"

I haven't found any good solution. I've been trying:

- unison: it is the only one working at the moment, but i had to do a lot of custom configurations (cron scripts that chains executions). It hangs my pc for many minutes to detect changes, disk light steady on.
- Sparkleshare doesn't handle large files nicely. It keeps an history of all your changes that grows up indefinitely. They promise it will be fixed in [next releases](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/wiki/Roadmap), but at the moment it still doesn't fit my needs.
- Owncloud doesn't handle large files nicely, has poor copy performances, keeps history of each file i change (can be disabled).
- coda ? (help! i couldn't set it up correctly!)
- [git-annex assistant](http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/) transforms all your files in symlinks and mark the original file as read only ("just in case you make a mistake while you modify it"!). Before you edit a file you have to issue a special command "git-annex unlock", that creates a local copy of the file, and you have to remember to lock it again if you want it synchronized. I had to study the manual before could get my 180Gb of files back! Never again on my pc!

What to try next?

Comment: What about rsync?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm necro'ing an old thread, but hopefully this will help someone in the future.

BTsync is probably a perfect option for you. It uses a private swarm and tracker to create sync shares. It is very fault tolerant and handles blocks of data well instead of just full file syncing.

[BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync)

Comment: +1 for btsync. i also think its ideal for this. Also its ok to necro an old question with a good answer. Particularly an otherwise unanswered one.